# Meesed up "Add to cart" button in product pages

Tags: product, magento-1.9, theme, custom, addtocart

Alright my store is behaving weird. some of the product pages are working fine but in some pages the "add to cart" button changes its position itself. I am attaching a thumbnail for the better understanding. please help out. thanks!!![image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the short description of such products, It seems any tag is not properly closed.

Comment: its Still same..!

Comment: are the product types same for both products

Comment: yes, they are same. actually i imported all the products from my previous store so there is no changes made to anything.

Comment: just use simple text in short description and save the product, then clear the cache and check

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't put that products into any head categories, they were just in sub-categories. but I don't know why that even matters. still thanks !!!